# Theming long lists of checkboxes- How can I divide lists of checkboxes into multiple columns?

Tags: theming

Some of the fields on my user edit pages contain very long (more than 10 items) lists of checkboxes.  How can I theme such lists so that they are displayed in multiple columns instead of one long list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
.form-radios,
.form-checkboxes {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.form-radios .form-item,
.form-checkboxes .form-item {
  font-size: 64%;
  width: 19%;         
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

and play around with the font-size and width to your specifics.  If you want to restrict this to a specific form, just add its id to the mix, eg:

```
#FORM .form-radios, ...
```

Comment: Make sure to throw this code in a media query, as it's better to just let it be a single column on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention if you use Drupal 7 or the content profile module.
But you can use this module for CCK (content in D7) field:
[multicolumncheckboxesradios](http://drupal.org/project/multicolumncheckboxesradios).
Worked well for me out of the box for a large project.

Comment: This is an interesting choice; thank you for point it out.  However, upon installing this module, I realized it achieves the multi-column effect by using tables, not pure css.  I think I will stay with pure css solution.